# How to give a href in a PHP while table

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I've gotten into trouble while working on a school project, and I'm stuck.
I'm making a website where you can easily search for amusement parks.

I made a while loop with PHP and put information from the DB into the table which I looped. I've put all the information in a TD and I want to create a-href so when I click on one of the first parks it will redirect to an example: example.php?park=1 for the second park example: example.php?park=2.

Here is the while:

```
  <div class="pretpark-container">
    <table id="pretpark-table">
      <?php while($pretpark = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      echo "<tr>";
      if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/img/'. $pretpark['ParkImage'])): ?>
      <td><img height="125px;" width="200px;"" src="/WikiParksWeb/Wikiparks-Website/img/<?php print($pretpark['ParkImage']); ?>"></td>
      <?php else: ?>
      <?php endif; 
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkName']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkLocation']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkOpeninsTime']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkPrices']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkShortDescription']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 
      ?> 
      <tr class="filler"></tr> 
      <?php
      }
      ?>       
    </table>     
  </div>
```

Each pretpark has an ID, the DB table of it is called ParkId.
Can someone help me where I have to put the a href. And how I can do it like its like this example: example.php?park= ParkId

I hope everything is understandable what I just said :/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<div class="pretpark-container">
    <table id="pretpark-table">
      <?php while($pretpark = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      echo "<tr>";
      if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/img/'. $pretpark['ParkImage'])): ?>
      <td><img height="125px;" width="200px;"" src="/WikiParksWeb/Wikiparks-Website/img/<?php print($pretpark['ParkImage']); ?>"></td>
      <?php else: ?>
      <?php endif; 
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkName']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkLocation']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkOpeninsTime']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkPrices']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkShortDescription']."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href='example.php?park=".$pretpark['Parkid']."'> More Details</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 
      ?> 
      <tr class="filler"></tr> 
      <?php
      }
      ?>       
    </table>     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="pretpark-container">
    <table id="pretpark-table">
      <?php while($pretpark = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      echo "<tr>";
      if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/img/'. $pretpark['ParkImage'])): ?>
      <td><img height="125px;" width="200px;"" src="/WikiParksWeb/Wikiparks-Website/img/<?php print($pretpark['ParkImage']); ?>"></td>
      <?php else: ?>
      <?php endif; 
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkName']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkLocation']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkOpeninsTime']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkPrices']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkShortDescription']."</td>";
      **echo "<td><a href='detailpage.php?id=".$pretpark['ParkId']."'></td>";**
      echo "</tr>"; 
      ?> 
      <tr class="filler"></tr> 
      <?php
      }
      ?>       
    </table>     
  </div>
```

I have added a line with bold formatting. You can get clue from this.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the line

```
 echo "<td>".$pretpark['ParkName']."</td>";
```

it would be something like..

```
echo "<td><a href=\"example.php?id=".$pretpark['ParkId']."\">".$pretpark['ParkName']."</a></td>";
```

backslashes are needed to escape the quotes so they come out in the HTML and are not interpreted by php